# Custom Play reverse routing

Tags: java, angularjs, scala, playframework, routes

General question here. Is it possible to overwite/extend the Play-Framework reverse routing to modify the URLs returned?

for example, if I have the route file entry:

```
GET        /views/index                             controllers.Application.index()
```

I would like to return /index instead of /views/index.

However, the call should be similar to that of the standard play reverse routing call:

```
@routes.Application.index()
```

in a Scala Template.

Reason for this is that I am decoupling my Play Backend from my AngularJS Frontend by using AngularJS Routing and the urls are different (missing the "/views") but I still want to be able to use the reverse routing feature of play.

Comment: 2nd column is the direction of the function which is written in controller. 
if you just write `GET  /index  controllers.Application.index()` you can see view of index controller(`index.scala.html`) when you type `http://yourlink/index`

Comment: @Ali19033 yeah true but that does not solve my problem. My problem is, that I am using AngularJS routing to navigate and resolve path parameters in my controllers. Reason for that is that I do not want to mix Scala with Angular. The AngularJS routes have to be different from the Play routes so they do not clash.